# Find typo with Lucene

Tags: lucene, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

I would like to use Lucene to index/search text. The text can contain mistyped words, names, etc. What is the most simple way of getting Lucene to find a document containing

```
"this is Licene"
```

when user searches for

```
"Lucene"?
```

This is only for a demo app, so we need the most simple solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lucene's fuzzy queries and based on Levenshtein edit distance.

Use a [fuzzy query](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches) in the QueryParser, with syntax like:

```
Lucene~0.5
```

Or create a [FuzzyQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html), passing in the maximum number of edits, something like:

```
Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("field", "lucene"), 1);
```

Note:  `FuzzyQuery`, in Lucene 4.x, does not support greater edit distances than 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I waited for other approaches or methods to surface, looks like this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Another option you could try is using the Lucene SpellChecker:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html

It is a out of box, and very easy to use:

```
  SpellChecker spellchecker = new SpellChecker(spellIndexDirectory);
  // To index a field of a user index:
  spellchecker.indexDictionary(new LuceneDictionary(my_lucene_reader, a_field));
  // To index a file containing words:
  spellchecker.indexDictionary(new PlainTextDictionary(new File("myfile.txt")));
  String[] suggestions = spellchecker.suggestSimilar("misspelt", 5);
```

By default, it is using the LevensteinDistance, but you could provide your own customized Edit Distance.